# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'get_data' on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to set an import modules from other python files but I'm been unable to fix it.

The file script is "energy_data" that has the script.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/tayzer/dags/tasks')

from datetime import timedelta

# The DAG object; we'll need this to instantiate a DAG
from airflow import DAG

# Operators; we need this to operate!
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

# Functions from other files
from get_data import load_data

#Default settings applied to all tasks
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id="Energy_Consumption",
    description='Energy Data ETL',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
)

t0 = BashOperator(
        task_id='print_date',
        bash_command='date',
)

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id = "load_AEP_hourly",
    python_callable = load_data,
    op_kwargs = {'filename':'AEP_hourly'},
    retries = 2
)
```

But on airflow I receive the error

```
Broken DAG: [/home/tayzer/workspace/dags/energy_data.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/tayzer/workspace/dags/energy_data.py", line 16, in <module>
    from get_data import load_data
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'get_data'
```

I already have a file called "settings.json" with the following info

```
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "./dags/tasks",
        "./dags/Libs"
    ]
}
```

And the "Get_data" file has the script

```
import pandas as pd
from utils import push_xcom_value

def load_data(filename):
    data = pd.read_csv(f"{filename}.csv").to_json()
```

and here you can find my file structures

[image]

Let me know if I need to add anything to help to fix this issue

Comment: i think it should be `from .get_data import load_data`, personally i think better would be to not `sys.path.append()` but to use `from .tasks.get_data import load_data` in `energy_data.py`

Comment: Thanksss, it worked using "from .tasks.get_data import load_data"

Comment: @TayzerDamasceno - Please add an answer for your question & close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a comment from @Bijay Regmi

I deleted `import sys` and `sys.path.append('/home/tayzer/dags/tasks')`

and stayed with `from tasks.get_data import load_data`

Comment: This must be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at PEP 328 that has details about Imports

https://peps.python.org/pep-0328/

Relative imports should have a leading `.` not to be confused with external or standard library packages

Comment: This is not really answering the question. Please delete it before attracting any -tive vote.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).